# Ground rod driver for very large ground rods?

Tags: grounding, tools

I have a large Jack/Demolition hammer I use this to pound very large ground rods/stakes into the soil.  These rods are those over 1” in diameter.

The largest rod driver I can find will fit 1” diameter rods. [This is it.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004RHG6) Most rod driver attachments are 3/4”. Sadly I can’t find any rod drivers that will fit rods larger than 1”!  Do any of these exist? Ideally with a 1-1/8” hex shank for attaching to my jack hammer.

Alternatively, I’d love suggestions for other more DIY solutions.  In the past I made a very DIY dapter for my 1” rod driver with plumbing pipe adapters to create something that fit in the rod driver but then extended out and flanged opened into a larger hole that would fit my ground rods. That worked for awhile but the weak metal in the plumbing adapters broke after a day of use.  Something similar but much stronger could work as well. [Here’s what that looks liked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lK4N.jpg)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What about large sockets as a DIY alternative to the plumbing adapter? Also, how big (diameter) are the rods you are driving?

Comment: I use a t post driver especially if I don't have temp power yet, in the past I used a section of 2" pipe with a welded plug prior to that being borrowed from my truck, needed one and there was a farm store have used that for years.

Comment: I'm curious; what's your  application? How long/thick would you like your ground rods to be?

Comment: Fence post driver to start(no ladder =no fall) then a custom built rig such as in this post. http://www.n4lcd.com/groundrod/      I knew one guy who got a welder to fabricate it out of steel.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a ground *rod* that chubby, instead of some other type of grounding electrode?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!! For context these are 4' steel rods with a 1" diameter.  (But the ends have been slightly flattened over time).  They're the stakes that keep a large "circus" tent in place so not using them for any electrical applications.  I could get another 100 rods that are skinnier but we already have these and their massive bulk ensures they'll never be bent out of place.

Comment: The large socket is a great idea! Any idea on how I might attach that to my Jack hammer?  Gonna research that a bit now. Thanks again!